# Tomcat: possible to exclude jars during app deployment?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

By default, Tomcat prevents webapps from loading several .jars which are part of the Tomcat distribution (eg the servlet and JSP APIs) - is it possible to configure others to also be excluded?

If it can't be done with configuration alone, does Tomcat provide any extension points for resource validation?

I want to use shared logging libraries, and need to make sure that an errant app doesn't clobber the configuration.

#### Example

This is what I'm referring to (from Tomcat startup log):

```
Oct 1, 2011 5:53:40 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(D:\tomcat\myapp\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api.jar) - jar not loaded.
See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2.
Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
```

Comment: I do not think tomcat Exclude any thing as such just a matter of classloading sequence which jar comes first in classpath . You are may be after this .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267953/managing-libraries-in-tomcat

Comment: @Shahzeb: I added an example. This isn't really about how the different classloaders interact - I want to be able to validate the resources that webapps try to load.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You check/filter what web apps load using a custom loader extending from `org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader` as mentioned in the [Tomcat documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/loader.html#Standard_Implementation).

Check out [Tomcat's implementation (7.0.19) of the standard `WebAppClassLoader`](https://zgrepcode.com/tomcat/9.0.14/org/apache/catalina/loader/webappclassloader.java) that implements the [filtering of `javax.servlet.Servlet`](https://zgrepcode.com/tomcat/9.0.14/org/apache/catalina/loader/webappclassloaderbase.java#L-2499) to get started. It's probably enough to override that class and just put some more entries into the `protected String[]` fields `triggers` and `packageTriggers`.

Comment: Of course, your custom `WebappClassLoader` should go into its own JAR in `TOMCAT_HOME/lib` away from your web apps, just to state the obvious :)